# R: merging nodes that have the same interactions from network table

Tags: r, networking, nodes, cytoscape

I have a large network table that I want to simplify by merging nodes that share the same interactions, so that it will have a better network once imaged (I am using Cytoscape). The interactions do not have direction. As a mini example, if I have a table such as below.

```
A  E
B  E
C  G
C  H
D  G
H  D
E  F
R  S
```

The two columns are nodes that interact with each other. In this case since nodes A, B and F all only have connections to node E, I want to merge them so it's A,B,F as one node that interacts with E. Similarly since both C and D only interact with G and H I would want to merge them together. The resulting table should look something like below.

```
A,B,F  E
C,D    G
C,D    H
R      S
```

I have created a list with all the nodes, but I am not sure how to see if they have matching interactions since they can be in either column. Is there a good way/program to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

For most networks, there would not be single solution to this problem. Once you start collapsing you begin to exclude other equally valid solutions. For example, even in your simplified example, these are other valid solutions:

A,B,F  E
G,H    C
G,H    D
R      S

or even

A,B,F  E
C,D    G,H
R      S

And it gets more complicated once you include interactions across your relatively clean example, e.g., A  G.  But if your data really is partitioned like this example (which should be immediately apparent when you load it into iGraph or Cytoscape and perform any basic layout to see a bunch of separate networks), then you might be able to get *a* solution by querying all interaction partners for each node, then collapsing based on identical partner sets.

I don't know of a function iGraph or Cytoscape that can do this for you.

And if you network is not a partitioned set of multiple networks, then I don't think this is feasible at all.

Comment: The network is completely interconnected without separate networks unfortunately, but thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0):

Do I understand it right, that your cytoscape graph contains all said elements and the 'interactions' stand for edges in cytoscape? Because if your network has said elements and edges, you could, for example (this will not be a fast solution I think), make an array with all id' of your elements with

```
cy.nodes();
```

and then call

```
Object.keys(cy.edges("[target = '" + nodeId + "']")).length;
```

on every node in the array and save the number of edges going out of said node in the array. This way you can find all nodes with at least x nodes attached and then you can do whatever you want. You could e.g make the selected nodes to parents, so that the connected nodes are now inside the parent nodes?

Please tell me if this helps you or not :)

Comment: The problem is that the table is so large that there are multiple nodes with the same number of connections but doesn't necessarily have the same partner node they are connecting to.

Comment: Is it possible to simply initialize the nodes you want to make more simple by giving them a parent element which makes said parent just a box containing the groups with same interactions? That would make the graph more readable I think. To get their relations you have the problem with not knowing on which side they are, maybe make the interactions have directions, makes it easier probably.